# Is it possible to use a laptop as a "router", using an old hub and connecting other devices to a wifi laptop?

Tags: laptop, router, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a wi-fi connection at home. My laptop uses it.

I want to use an old ethernet hub that I have, connect two ethernet cables (one in a ps3, one in a media center) on it, and a cable going to my ethernet port in my pc.

I want to these devices to be able to see all machines like they were "wi-fi" too, possilby sharing a folder in my laptop so the media box and the ps3 would see it. My pc would be a "bridge" between the original wi-fi router. If possible, I would like to give ips to these ethernet machines using DHCP from my router (I believe this DHCP need is difficult or impossible).

Is this possible? I'm using Windows 7 64bits and Debian Lenny 5.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. In control panel -> network connections, I right-click on my WiFi adapter (not the virtual wifi port) and then Properties, and then click on the sharing tab. I put a checkmark in "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection". Under Home Networking Connection drop-down, I chose "Local Area Connection" which is my laptop's LAN NIC.
3. I unchecked Allow other computers to control...
4. OK
5. Make sure the LAN NIC you will use for connecting to the other computer has any static IP configurations removed and set to DHCP.
6. Make sure the LAN NIC on the desktop you will connect to is set to DHCP also.
7. Connect a crossover cable from the laptop to the Desktop.
8. If it's windows vista or 7, then it should connect and present you with the "Home network, Public Network, Work Network." Choose appropriately. 
   You should now be connected! If the desktop doesn't automatically connect, you may want to "Diagnose" or "Repair" the LAN connection.

Source: http://discussions.virtualdr.com/archive/index.php/t-237754.html

Comment: What about this line:  "Is this possible? I'm using Windows 7 64bits and Debian Lenny 5.0.5."  From the original question.  The PS3 is one device, media center another, and the two OSes mentioned are Windows 7 and Debian...  Plus the question mentions "pc."

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that.  Revising my answer now.

Comment: updated with what should work for windows 7 using a crossover cable from your laptop to whatever you need to connect to.  I'm not sure if the crossover cable will work with the PS3 although it might.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a **bridging** between the WiFi and Ethernet networks, so all computers should see each other in one virtual network. The router especially should see them all, and therefore might be able to serve as DHCP-master and let everybody access the Internet (depending on the firmware).

As I suppose that the old PC has Windows XP, here are some useful articles:
[Windows XP Home Networking: Building Network Bridges](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/crawford_02april22.mspx)
[Configuring Windows XP as a Network Bridge](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/wxpbrdge.html)
(but they should apply equally well to later Windows versions, with some modifications)