# Connect two wireless routers

Tags: wireless-networking, router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buying another router and use as a “signal repeater” in bridge mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/166558/buying-another-router-and-use-as-a-signal-repeater-in-bridge-mode)

Hi,

is it possible (and if yes, can someone please direct me to a site which can give me more info on how to) connect 2 wireless routers?

The thing is, I have a small buisness, and I would like to have just one internet connection. So far it's been done by sending the wireless signal through the router which is conencted to the main DSL/Cable modem, but as the company is expanding, some offices have trouble reciving that signal.

So I was wondering if I can connect one router to the main DSL/Cable modem, send the signal to some computers there and send a signal to another router about 100m distant so it can send signals to some computers there.

Or if that is not possible, maybe just have the first router send the signal to another one so that JUST the other ona can send recived signals to the computers there?

I hope i'm beeing clear :)

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: routers i'm using are both EDIMAX BR-6226n

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use one as a repeater.

http://www.computer-aid.com.au/blog/2011/02/06/configuring-an-edimax-br-6226n-as-a-wireless-repeater/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=wifi+repeaters&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=5872740843227684656&ei=dqtRTdmoEcP68Abp8dy0Cg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CE0Q8wIwAg#

You can use one of these wifi range extenders.
However, I think that it would be easier to connect second wifi router with a cat5 cable.  It all depends on what you find more comfortable to setup.

Answer (score 0):

What you're hoping to do is set up a repeater, if I'm not mistaken.  This is something you should be able to set up from the configuration page.  I would do a search for that.